# When sending a get request to api, I get an error: has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: node.js, express, cors

When sending a get request to api, I get an error: has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Although the domain is specified in the CORS settings on the api server, other types of requests:

> (POST, GET from other pages of the site)

are sent normally. In what there can be a problem?

**API call code**

```
const res = await axios.get(
            `${process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL}/checkmail/${this.mail}`, {withCredentials: true}
        )
```

```
var corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['https://DOMAIN', 'http://localhost:8080'],
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'UPDATE', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS'],
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

**What do I get in the network tab**

**General**

```
Request URL: https://api.DOMAIN/checkmail/EXEMPLEMAIL@gmail.com
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403 
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Response Headers**

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 199
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:04:57 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2o-fips
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,ru-RU;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk;q=0.6
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: 
Host: api.DOMAIN
Origin: https://DOMAIN
Referer: https://DOMAIN/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score -1):

first match your url from backend side 
second simply use `app.use(cors());`
if does not work above method then try below method

manually set header like this

```
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authortization');
    res.setHeader('Acces-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick response. Already tried this approach. But alas, unsuccessfully. The error remains.

Comment: try to open same url in the new tab maybe  error resolve

Comment: It would be so simple) Unfortunately, even in another browser, the error remained. Why can some get requests work and others don't?